# Lyx - unable to find bind file for keyboard shortcuts

Tags: lyx, keyboard

After adding a custom shortcut, Lyx complains that it can't find the .bind file, and also a bunch of keyboard shortcuts (such as adding sections) are missing. I checked and there's a bunch of keyboard binding files in /usr/share/lyx/bind:

[image]

Is there a bind file missing? Is there any way of 'repairing' Lyx so that the default bindings come back?

Comment: See also this forum post on [restoring the default bind file in Lyx](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21551) "1. Open LyX and go to About LyX. Write down your User directory (this should be copyable in the next version).
2. Exit LyX
3. Navigate to where your User directory is and delete it (actully, just move it so that you can restore it if necessary).
4. Restart LyX"

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had accidentally typed in the Bind file: entry instead of the Show key bindings containing entry when I was trying to make the new shortcut, which obviously messed things up. After loading up the various key binding files, I think the one that I wanted (i.e. the default key binding) is sciword.

Comment: cua.bind is default, but some users prefer sciword if they used to use that software before LyX.